# Wifi not working on one laptop but working on another

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I have a problem with WiFi connection on my laptop. On my phone and other laptop wifi speed is around `30-40 Mbit/s` (internet provider on the cable is `50 Mbit/s`, so wifi is a bit slowed which is fine), but as soon as I turn my PC on the speed on my phone goes to `0.5 - 5 Mbit/s` at max, and it goes back again to `30-40 Mbit/s` when I turn off my laptop.

And the same speed is on my laptop when I connect it to the same WiFi (Asus one). Also connection might break at some point and connect again after few seconds or a minute. But always the problem with this laptop.

I have dual boot (Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04) on my Asus K555L. On Ubuntu when I cat the sys logs I get that message a lot `CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS`. Also I upgrades my laptop from 6GB to 12GB of RAM, if that makes any difference.

Noticed that these things started when I received my laptop from service, where they did a dual boot. Also wifi driver is `Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter` (version 10.0.3.462, which is the latest version).
Tried with adding the google`s DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in settings, also with flushdns and other options. Ethernet connection doesn't work at all.

Nothing worked for me. Any idea how to solve this? Can this be the problem with IP and router since it's only the problem with this laptop?

Comment: You mean that WiFi is broken on the laptop for both Windows and Ubuntu? If you have in Windows enabled System Restore, then rollback Windows to before you sent it for service. If this also doesn't work, return the computer to be serviced again (without causing damage this time).

Comment: What happens if you boot the Asus from USB, e.g., Win RE or Ubuntu? If the issue still occurs, WiFi *hardware* has been damaged. As @harrymc states, *document* the issue and go back to the place it was serviced.

Comment: Alternatively, try a USB WLAN dongle and check if the problem persists

Comment: @harrymc Yes WiFi is broken on the laptop for both OS. So I assume it's laptop thing.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik So 2 hours ago I restarted modem and I had the WiFi that worked fine for 2 hours until I restarted the laptop, then same problem again..

Comment: @Albin, I can't even connect using cable

Comment: In my opinion: The service ruined your laptop, return and demand a repair.